# Trying to download a file with WebClient that contains a ':' in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, uri, webclient

I'm trying to download a file with a colon ':' in the URL and I get an exception with that character in the URL string. For example: http://www.somesite.com/url:1/ would create an exception in the WebClient. What is another way to download files using URI or how can I fix this exception?

Here's some sample code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile("http://www.somesite.com/url:1/", somePath);
```

Comment: "an exception" is usually not very helpful; can you be more specific, including the exact exception message and any inner-exception messages?

Comment: I apologize. The mistake was not due to UrlEncoding. After some more analysis of the exception, I learned that I for some reason had a ':' in my local filepath. This is due to the how I was saving the file to my local machine. I wasn't paying attention to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to URL encode the colon (`%3A`).

I always use [this site](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to encode or decode URL's.

Your example would be like this then:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile("http://www.somesite.com/url%3A1/", somePath);
```

Answer (score 2):

Many special characters can't be contained in path part of the URL. You will have to encode that part and concatenate it with server address. You can do this using [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)

```
string url = "http://www.somesite.com/" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("url:1/");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the URI using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`. See [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx). If it is static than just use the fixed character translation (`%3A`).

Answer (score 1):

`WebClient` has no complaint about this:

```
using(var client = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        client.DownloadFile(
            "http://stackoverflow.com/users/541404/fake:1",
            @"j:\MyPath\541404.html");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        while (ex != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            ex = ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
}
```

works fine. So; I think you need to look again at the `Exception` (and any `InnerException`), to see what the problem **actually** is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, but all browsers subsititute illegal characters with "%" + ASCII code (hexa), so maybe you can try `"%3A"` instead ":". Like: `"http://www.somesite.com/url:1/"`